# how to convert json to string

Tags: php, mysql, json

how do i convert a json object to a string

i want to insert a json object to a mysql DB

Comment: Exactly what is a "json object" in php?

Comment: the output of json_encode is a string! what json object are you talking about?

Answer (score 26):

You might be interested in [json_encode()](http://docs.php.net/json_encode).

On the other hand if you already got something json encoded then it already is a string and you can simply store it as-is in the database.

Comment: Old post but, can you tell me why I get these `\n` instead of `new line` in my string? I need to `json_encode($data)` to store to Redis (as string). And later `json_decode($string)` to get my values from a json..

Comment: That's just how a linebreak is encoded in JSON (and javascript). When it gets parsed the `\n` "becomes" a linebreak again, see https://jsfiddle.net/tafodvn5/

Comment: Yep, found out the hard way late at night :p Anyway thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 10):

JSON itself is a string.
People use json_encode() and json_decode() to convert objects/arrays of PHP to string and back to objects/arrays.

Comment: JSON is not a string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54122999/is-json-a-string/54123061

Comment: @MihaiGalan That answer is misleading. JSON is a format, but its data is stored in a string.

Answer (score -2):

$array = json_decode($json,true);
$string = implode(",",$array);

Now you can save this string in db as text.

Comment: This isn't really adding anything to the question that's not yet been added. Also, please use code formatting to make code more readable.